# How to consume affiliate's api in an effective way

Tags: api, wordpress, affiliate

Hi I am running a Coupon website and I'm new to WP development. I do know how to consume product feeds using affiliate's API. But my question is how to consume it in an effective way.

I would like to automate the process of getting feeds using cron job with transient. But product feeds from API are so huge, and I have no idea of how to consume in an effective and periodic way.

Also I believe doing cron job for long time will leads some negative impact...

So any help is appreciated :)